# BASH: Redirect time with read command

Tags: bash, time, io-redirection

I need to time how much it takes to the user to write a specific sentence in input, in a script.

I've tried with this:

```
TIMEFORMAT=%R
{ time read -n53 -t45 -e userstring } 2> time.txt
```

But when I write the sentence in the stdin the terminal doesn't show it; If I cat the time.txt file, it appears like this:

```
Ma la volpe col suo balzo ha raggiunto il quieto fido

real    0m7.537s
user    0m0.002s
sys   0m0.003s
```

EDIT: the problem seems to be the -e options; it doesn't show the stdin while the user is typing the sentences and it redirects it to time.txt file

Comment: You cannot set variables in a subshell that are accessible outside that shell.  Children cannot modify their parents environment, that said, why are you running that in a subshell anyway?

Comment: Use a code block instead i.e `{ your commands ; } 2> file`

Comment: @EricRenouf I read somewhere that if I want to save the time result for further processing I have to run it in a Subshell, is it wrong?

Comment: @123 it doesn't change anything, the time.txt file result the same

Comment: @fumass Sorry I don't understand what your problem is. What do you want to happen?

Comment: @fumass yes, that is wrong.  You can redirect any command you want and its stdout/stderr go to a file.  If you want to do it with a group of commands without a subshell you can use 123's advice, though for a single command it isn't necessary

Comment: @123 I need to store only the time in the time.txt file, but it store also the sentence "Ma la volpe col suo balzo raggiunse il quieto Fido" which it suppose to be wrote in the stdin

Comment: @EricRenouf the time keyword must be in the code block or outside of it?

Comment: `time` will measure the time for whatever you pass it, so if you want to measure the time for a single command, just put `time` before the one command, if you want to measure the time for the whole block, put it outside the block

Comment: Ok, it works fine, the problem is the -e read options which it doesn't show the stdin while I'm writing the sentence but it redirect to the time.txt file

Comment: If one-second precision is all you need, just take the value of `$SECONDS` before and after the `read` command. If you need sub-second precision, you should probably be using a different language.

Comment: @chepner yes, it would be a lot easier with other languages, I know; but I have to do it with shell scripting. Also the timer must start when the user press the first key

Comment: They you *really* cannot do this in shell. The `time` command starts ticking as soon as `read` starts to run, because it just reads from a file. It doesn't know or care that that "file" is actually a terminal that reads from the keyboard.